# Array validation in Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, validation, laravel, laravel-5

I am developing a quiz application in Laravel and I have some problems with the [array validation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/validation#validating-arrays). I use AngularJS on the front end and I use ajax in order to send objects to the Laravel API.
This is a sample JSON object :

```
{"name":"TestName","category":"TestCategory","questions":[{"answers":[{"type":"radio","information":"Test answer two","is_correct":false,"$$hashKey":"object:28"},{"type":"radio","information":"Test answer One","is_correct":false,"$$hashKey":"object:22"}],"$$hashKey":"object:13","question_text":"Test Question One"}]}
```

The quiz has name, category and questions. Each question must have question_text and answers. Each answer has type, information and is_correct.

Here is the validation I wrote :

```
   $this->validate($request, [
            'name' => 'required|min:3',
            'category' => 'required|min:2',
            'questions' => 'required',
            'questions.*.question_text' => 'required|min:5',
            'questions.*.answers' => 'required'

        ]);
```

The name and category validations work fine. The third validation ('questions => 'required') works fine as well. The rest of the validations do nothing. 
For example,

```
{"name":"SomeName","category":"SomeCategory","questions":[{}]}
```

passes the validation although the questions array has an element that doesn't have answers or question_text field. How does the array validation work ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a known issue.

There is an open pull request that addresses the "required" validation. You can follow this [pull request here](https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/11885).

There is also a second pull request that addresses the issue with the "required_*" validations (required_with, etc.). You can follow that [pull request here](https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/11927).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I've never pulled  something from github, so I have no idea how to do that. Can you give me some directions ? I have git (bash) installed.

Comment: @Kockar It's not something that you do. At some point, if it is acceptable, Taylor will merge the pull request(s) into Laravel, tag a new release, and then you'll need to run a `composer update` to get the latest Laravel version. You just need to keep an eye on the pull requests to see when they're merged in, so you know when to update.